# How to run multiple commands one after another in bash?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

How do I run multiple commands, one after another, in bash? Alternatively, how do I activate multiple datapipelines?

So far I have:

```
 aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id df-
 aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id df-
 aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id df-
```

And so on, where `aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id dfXXXXXXX` is an individual command for activating a datapipeline in AWS. I have another 30 pipelines to activate. So, what I am trying to do is to put these commands in a file as a script and execute them one by one.

However, when I put them into one file,  somehow it is getting considered as one command and it is failing. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @ashishvarshney, There is no need to write same command so many times, You should explain in detail what are you trying to do,what you have done yet or/and any other details, If necessary.

Comment: aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id dfXXXXXXX is an individual command for activating datapipeline in AWS. I have another 30 pipelines to activate. So, what I am trying to is, put in a file as a script and execute them one by one. When I am putting them one file somehow it is getting considered as one command and it failed.

Comment: Does the first command in the script work from the command line?